# Click checkbox within TR element

Tags: html, dom

I'd like to select the checkbox based on the user email. I try somethig like this but doesn't work: "InvalidStateError: An exception was thrown  debugger eval code:1".

```js
$x("//span[text()='my.user@mydomain.com']/parent::div/previousElementSibling::td");
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```html
    <td class="col checkUser selection">
        <div class="checkbox um-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="option1">
            <label data-select-checkbox="" data-ngretain="u-cd324c08-f215-5784-87b7-98944b18819f"></label>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="col userData item-collapse item-top">
        <div class="showUserDetails" title="My User" data-id="u-cd324c08-f215-5784-87b7-98944b18819f">
            <span class="text-overflow " style="max-width: 90%;display: inline-block;">
            <span class="first-name">My </span>
            <span class="first-name">User </span>
            </span>
            <span>
        <a href="#" class="hide" style="display: inline-block;"><img style="height: 24px;width:24px;margin-left: 5px;" src="/Admin/img/admin-gray.svg"></a>
        </span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="col userData item-collapse item-top">
        <div class="showUserDetails text-overflow" title="my.user@mydomain.com" data-id="u-cd324c08-f215-5784-87b7-98944b18819f">
            <span class="first-name">my.user@mydomain.com </span>
        </div>
    </td>
```

Comment: What happend when it "doesn't work"?

Comment: I've edited my question to include the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`previousElementSibling` is not a XPath selector but a property on a element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling

An almost similar selector for a XPath is the `preceding-sibling` selector. But that will return all the preceding siblings so you will have to maximize the result to 1 with the `[1]` selector:

```
/preceding-sibling::div[1]
```

And then you still need to only select the divs containing the checkbox class so you will need the `[contains(@class, 'checkbox')]` selector and select the input with the `/input` selector.

The complete selector for the checkbox then looks like this:

```js
$x("//span[text()='my.user@mydomain.com']/parent::div/preceding-sibling::div[contains(@class, 'checkbox')][1]/input")
```

If however you are using `document.evaluate` instead of `$x` you will need to replace the `text()='the text'` selector with the `contains(. ,'the text')` selector because the text() selector does not work in the `document.evaluate` method.

The complete executable code snippet:

```js
var doc = document.children[0].children[1];
var checkbox = document.evaluate(
    "//span[contains(., 'my.user@mydomain.com')]/parent::div/preceding-sibling::div[contains(@class, 'checkbox')][1]/input",
    doc,
    null,
    XPathResult.ANY_TYPE,
    null
).iterateNext()

console.log(checkbox)
alert(checkbox)
```

```html
 <td class="col checkUser selection">
        <div class="checkbox um-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="option1">
            <label data-select-checkbox="" data-ngretain="u-cd324c08-f215-5784-87b7-98944b18819f"></label>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="col userData item-collapse item-top">
        <div class="showUserDetails" title="My User" data-id="u-cd324c08-f215-5784-87b7-98944b18819f">
            <span class="text-overflow " style="max-width: 90%;display: inline-block;">
            <span class="first-name">My </span>
            <span class="first-name">User </span>
            </span>
            <span>
        <a href="#" class="hide" style="display: inline-block;"><img style="height: 24px;width:24px;margin-left: 5px;" src="/Admin/img/admin-gray.svg"></a>
        </span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="col userData item-collapse item-top">
        <div class="showUserDetails text-overflow" title="my.user@mydomain.com" data-id="u-cd324c08-f215-5784-87b7-98944b18819f">
            <span class="first-name">my.user@mydomain.com </span>
        </div>
    </td>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I get back a zero length array if I try the suggested solution. I also tried: $x("//span[text()='my.user@mydomain.com']/parent::div/preceding-sibling::div[contains(@class, 'checkbox')][1]/input").click() but then I get- TypeError: $x(...).click is not a function.

Comment: @János I've edited my answer with a working code snippet. Also, I had to replace the `text` selector with the `contains` selector to make it work in a code example because you can use $x in the developer console but not in javascript code in a website.